# Cant change objects' property - Writing to ID classes in this context is not allowed. location: <unknown location>:-1

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I can change object's property using operator or just pasting `bpy.data.objects["BF_platform_twelve"].hide_viewport = True` at the beigining of file or in python console, but i need to change object's property by changing drop down value only.
This works fine, but i need to get rid of button.

[image]

When im just checking value everything works fine except editing objects property

```
layout.prop(mytool, "my_enum")

if mytool.my_enum == 'OP0':
     bpy.data.objects["BF_platform_twelve"].hide_viewport = True #Writing to ID classes in this context is not allowed. location: <unknown location>:-1
     layout.prop(camera, "lens", text="Угол обзора") #This works fine
```

Error:

`Python: Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\desktop\BF_Default.blend\blenderfight.py", line 51, in draw AttributeError: Writing to ID classes in this context is not allowed: BF_platform_twelve,  Object datablock, error setting Object.hide_viewport  location: <unknown location>:-1`

Full code:

```
import bpy

class MyProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    my_enum : bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name= "",
        description= "sample text",
        items= [('OP0', "Ничего", ""),
                ('OP1', "Квадрат", ""),
                ('OP2', "Двенадцатигранник", "")
        ]
    )


class Platform_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Платформа"
    bl_idname = "Platform_Panel111"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "BlenderFight"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool
        camera = bpy.data.cameras[bpy.context.scene.camera.name]
        render=bpy.data.scenes[0].render
        cycles=bpy.context.scene.cycles
        
        layout.prop(mytool, "my_enum")

        if mytool.my_enum == 'OP0':
            bpy.data.objects["BF_platform_twelve"].hide_viewport = True #Writing to ID classes in this context is not allowed. location: <unknown location>:-1
            layout.prop(camera, "lens", text="Угол обзора") #This works fine
 
 
classes = [MyProperties, Platform_Panel]
 
 
 
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
        bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type= MyProperties)
 
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool
 
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: You cannot alter data in a draw method.

Comment: Also simply use `camera = scene.camera` there is no need for `camera = bpy.data.objects[bpy.context.scene.camera.name]` which will not work if there is no scene camera.

Answer (score 0):

Draw Def using only for UI. 
I had to add "update" in DD menu props that call a function in case value was changed

```
def common_update(self, context, origin):
    if origin == 'my_enum':
        print('button_one', getattr(self, origin))
        # bpy.data.objects["Macbook_Gold"]["00_iSight Camera Indicator"] = getattr(self, origin)

class MyProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
my_enum : bpy.props.EnumProperty(
    update=lambda self, context: common_update(self, context, 'my_enum'), #<------------
    name= "",
    description= "sample text",
    items= [('OP0', "Ничего", ""),
            ('OP1', "Квадрат", ""),
            ('OP2', "Двенадцатигранник", "")
    ]
)
```